# Is it wrong to place a constant qualified inline member function before an access specifier?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, constants

I came across something strange in Visual Studio.

If you place a member function which is `const` qualified (i.e.; ends with `const`), you are not allowed to place an access specifier (i.e.; `public`, `protected` or `private`) right after it.

[image]

```
    // ...
    int GetFour() { return 4; } const
private:
    static ClassName * Instance;
    Settings();
    // ...
```

And everything gets fixed (compiles and runs with no errors) if you change the order of member function prototypes and place a non-const member function before the access specifier.

[image]

```
    // ...
    int GetFour() { return 4; } const
    int GetFive() { return 5; }
private:
    static ClassName * Instance;
    ClassName();
    // ...
```

I want to know if this is a rule in C++, just a bug in Visual Studio or something I did?

(Version: Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Update 3)

Comment: 4 out of 5 Python programmers agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int GetFour() { return 4; } const
```

Wrong place.

This is correct:

```
int GetFour() const { return 4; }
```

That is, `const` appears right after the function's `()` and before `{`.

---

The following code will compile:

```
int GetFour() { return 4; } const
int NonConstFunc();
```

because `const` after the `}` is considered as the *part* of return type of the next function. So the above is actually this:

```
int GetFour() { return 4; }  
const int NonConstFunc();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong. You are placing the `const` after the function definition. You need this:

```
int GetFour() const { return 4; }
//            ^^^^^
```

The reason your second variant does not produce a compiler error is that it gets parsed like this

```
int GetFour() { return 4; } 
const int GetFive() { return 5; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `const` is in the wrong place.  It should be right before the `{`.

```
int GetFour() const { return 4; }
```